# MySQL get list of tables ending with specific name and it's (table's) comment

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, postgresql, information-schema

I have multiple tables in my multiple databases.
On different servers, i use MySQL / PostgreSQL / MS SQL.
I keep short table names
but the comments given to the tables are with full explanation.

I want query that will show me tables ending with "com" and also the comment given to each table (table's comment).

In MySQL, I know:
`SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables where table_name like "%com"`

But this shows all tables from all databases.

Comment: For a specific database, add a filter on `TABLE_CATALOG`. AFAIK, `TABLE_COMMENT` is not part of the ISO SQL standard and not available in all the DBMS products in  your question.

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL, check out following:

`SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables;`

will show all table names in all databases;

`SELECT table_name,table_comment FROM information_schema.tables`

will show all table names + comment in all databases;


interesting thing, you can fire

`SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables;`

to know what all info you can get of a table.

```
SELECT table_name,table_comment FROM information_schema.tables 
where 
table_schema = 'sifr_b';
```

will show all table names + comment in "sifr_b" database;

```
SELECT table_name,table_comment FROM information_schema.tables 
where 
table_schema = 'sifr_b' and 
table_name like "%com";
```

will show those table names + comment in "sifr_b" database, that have table name **ending with "com"**;

Comment: `_` is the LIKE wildcard for _any single character_. I.e. I'd expect tables ending with "com", and having at least 4 characters.

Comment: SO is not a blog. And this will fail for sql server as already noted.

Comment: @SMor why have you said "SO is not a blog"?